# My oledb connection string has a " in it so is not recognized

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Im trying to run an update statement and when i go to data sources to grab the connection string it has a " in it which means when i try to add it to the line;

```
OleDbConnection(Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MasterDB.accdb")
```

It wont accept it, I tried to & & it but then i still need double speech marks.
is there some sort of way to force vb.net to ignore the speechmark? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to specify the quotes around your DataSource, however you should add the database name here (the .ACCDB file)

Comment: Sorry i miscopied the path its actually        Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\Student\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MasterDB.accdb"  my problem is that when i declare it it wants a string and gived me an error on the provider part if i don't.

Comment: have you tried doulbe-quotes `... Source=""C:\....accdb""...`?

Comment: The call to the OleDbConnection constructor requires that EVERYTHING is passed as a string. From the ("Provider=.........MasterDB.accdb"), You remove the quotes only around the DataSource=",,,," and leave just the closing one

Comment: Yeah first thing i tried, It just makes the code think the text i wanted was inbetween the two double quotes making it not run at all.

Comment: Wow Steve it was that simple been sitting here for an half an hour bashing my head against a wall. Thanks alot

Comment: I see where the problems started. But this is not a command line....